# FileSystemEventHandler method as parameter

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I have the following method that sets up a FileSystemEventHandler to monitor for changes to a config.xml file.

```
public void WatchConfigFile(???)
{
    this.watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    DirectoryInfo _di = Directory.GetParent(configFile);
    this.watcher.Path = _di.FullName;
    this.watcher.Filter = Path.GetFileName(configFile);
    this.watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.CreationTime;
    this.watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(???);
    this.watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    log.Info("Config watcher established at " + watcher.Path);
}
```

I would like to add this method to a library of standard methods we use over and over but do not know how to pass the onChanged method handler to the method and assign it to the watcher.  The method represented by ??? (to handle the changes) would be something like this:

```
public void ConfigFileChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    // Do something when file is updated
}
```

I would like to be able to call this as follows:

```
_library.WatchConfigFile(ConfgiFileChanged);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it sounds like you just want the handler itself as the parameter:

```
public void WatchConfigFile(FileSystemEventHandler handler)
{
    ...
    this.watcher.Changed += handler;
    ...
}
```

That should be fine. There'll be a method group conversion from `ConfigFileChanged` to `FileSystemEventHandler` when you call `WatchConfigFile`.

(Bear in mind that currently your `WatchConfigFile` method *replaces* the current contents of `this.watcher`... so if you call it twice, you won't have a reference to the first watcher any more. Perhaps you want a `List<FileSystemWatcher>` instead?)

Comment: Thank you!  I was making it more difficult than necessary.  Also like the idea of a List<FileSystemWatcher>.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to use [delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx).

- create the *definition* of the delegate
- define in your class a method of type your custom delegate
- assign the handler method to the field of your class or use it as parameter

Delegate:

```
public delegate void ConfigFileChangedHandler(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e);
```

The class using the delegate can look like this:

```
public class Dummy
{
    public ConfigFileChangedHandler FileChangedHandler { get; set; }
    public void UseTheAction(ConfigFileChangedHandler action)
    {
        // invoke
        action(this, null);
        // or bind
        // object.Event += action;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var dummy = new Dummy();
dummy.FileChangedHandler += ConfigFileChanged;
dummy.UseTheAction(ConfigFileChanged);

private void ConfigFileChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Event fired");
}
```